# Where to place trained Speech model

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I have trained pocketsphinx using sphinxtrain. The problem I'm facing is that I don't know how to use the trained model in my code.

My first thought was to just replace the current model in the pocketsphinx library or to include the trained model somehow.

I have searched a lot but most of what I found was based around using tensorflow for training or Googles recognition software, but nothing about how to use a trained model.

Here is a basic example of how the code works:

```
import speech_recognition as sr


r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = r.listen(source)



output = r.recognize_sphinx(audio)
print(output)
```

Comment: speech_recognition module is flawed, use pocketsphinx-python instead

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev  I made a script using the recommended code for LiveSpeech, but i can't use the recognized phrase even though it displays it when i print it. How do i fix this?

Comment: show the code you wrote

Comment: `from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech


for phrase in LiveSpeech():

 if phrase in ['hello ', 'hi']:
  print("recognized")
  print(phrase) 
 else:
  print("not recognized")
  print(phrase)
`
It doesn't recognize the word "hello" even though it prints as hello in print(phrase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using pocketsphinx's `LiveSpeech()`

```
import os
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech, get_model_path
model_path = get_model_path()

speech = LiveSpeech(
    verbose=False,
    sampling_rate=16000,
    buffer_size=2048,
    no_search=False,
    full_utt=False,
    hmm=os.path.join(model_path, 'en-us'),
    lm=os.path.join(model_path, 'en-us.lm.bin'),
    dic=os.path.join(model_path, 'cmudict-en-us.dict')
)

for phrase in speech:
    output = phrase.hypothesis()

    if output == 'hello':
        print("recognized")
        print(output)
    else:
        print("not recognized")
        print(output)
```

In this example the output should look something like this for the if statement

```
recognized
hello
```

and like this for the else statement

```
not recognized
hi
```